# Can Any body explain where all route mapping details save in MVC 4 .Net

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to know How and where .net framework save all route mapping details(Route table).

Answer (score 1):

in `AppStart` Folder

File Name is `RouteConfig.cs`